# python get by index for a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, subclass

I have subclass that inherits from a dict. On `__getitem__` method I'd like to check whether the key is numeric or not. If it is numeric I'd like to implement some other behavior and if it not then I'd like continue as it would normally do. Example:

```
class M(dict):
   ...
   def __getitem__(self, key):
      if self.isNumber(key):
          print "I am number"
      else:
          # continue the same way as it would have done
   ...

>>> x = M({"name": "Tom", "surname": "Baker", "age": "55"})
>>> print x["name"]
Tom
>>> x[0]
I am number
```

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I know that items in dict are hashed therefore it will not be in order, the reason behind what I ask is something else. And since I'm sure you'll still ask why, this is the reason: The dict is an object and I will retrieve the objects related to the given object by their index. (Think as parent, child stuff)

Comment: call the parent implementation?

Comment: Once you know it's easy :) I did not know that I could call parent's implementation, I thought the __getitem__ was overriding it. Apparently, people do not support other people who are trying to understand, so they just give a minus point. Anyways, I got my lesson. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for...

```
class M(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            temp = int(key)
            return "I am a number"
        except ValueError:
            return self.get(key, None)

item = M({'one':'1', 'two':'2', '3':'three'})

print item['one']
print item[3]
print item[0]
```

As mentioned by @bpgergo, you can also use `super`.

So the return would look like this:

```
    except ValueError:
        return super(M, self).__getitem__(key)
```

The big difference here is that my way would (perhaps poorly) suppress any KeyError that was raised because you tried to access a key that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
# continue the same way as it would have done
```

Here use the `super()` function. (this is not a joke)
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Is it obligatory to use `super()` or could the OP use something like `dict.__getittem_(key)`?

Comment: When you know the parent class, specifying it directly works, but `super` is considered idiomatic and is more flexible (automatically continues to work if weird things happen to your inheritance hierarchy). That said, I usually don't bother with `super` myself :)

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to invoke the parent class's `__getitem__` method in the case of the key not being numeric. This is done with the super() function. See the example below:

```
class cls(dict):
     def __getitem__(self, key):
         if isinstance(numbers.Number):
             print "I am a number"
         else:
             return super(cls, self).__getitem__(key)
```

Comment: `type(key) == int` misses all `int` subclasses and `long`. `isinstance(key, (int, long, float))` would be preferable, or even better `isinstance(key, numbers.Number)` or `isinstance(key, numbers.Integral)`.

Comment: Quite true! Thanks for sharing that. I haven't used these abstract base classes before :) Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

You need to index by the list of the keys for the dictionary.
Example:

```
x = dict({"name": "Tom", "surname": "Baker", "age": "55"})
print x[x.keys()[0]]
'55'
```

Edit: As I suspected, the order is not guaranteed.

> "Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random,
>   varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary's
>   history of insertions and deletions. If items(), keys(), values(),
>   iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no
>   intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly
>   correspond. This allows the creation of (value, key) pairs using
>   zip(): "pairs = zip(a.values(), a.keys())". The same relationship
>   holds for the iterkeys() and itervalues() methods: "pairs =
>   zip(a.itervalues(), a.iterkeys())" provides the same value for pairs.
>   Another way to create the same list is "pairs = [(v, k) for (k, v) in
>   a.iteritems()]"."

Source: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html

With this in mind, I think its better not assume that SLA from a dictionary (That the keys' order will not change)

Comment: Ahh! I get it. I thought the OP was asking how to get a value by index. Although, if you look at the title, thats what it says: "python get by index for a dictionary"